# Pass a function's return value to an event handler

Tags: javascript, html

I am self-learning Javascript, and wrote the following code to understand event handlers.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script language=Javascript>
    function sum(first, second) {
      // return first + second
      return 42
    }

    function update(label, value) {
      document.getElementById(label).innerHTML = value
    }

    function foo() {
      return 42
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="f1">
    One: <input type=text name=firstNum value=""><br>
    Two: <input type=text name=secondNum value=""><br>
    Sum: <label type=text id="OutSum"></label><br>

    <input type=button value='Update' onClick='update("OutSum", sum(4, 5))'> // <----
  </form>
```

The intention is to eventually display the sum of two numbers entered in the textboxes. Since that isn't working, I am going through intermediate steps to figure out where the problem lies.

I am having trouble with the line marked by arrow `// <----` above. If I instead replace it with the below, then the code works.

```
<input type=button value='Update' onClick='update("OutSum", foo())'>
```

Do I need to use a different syntax if the method takes parameters?

PS: I realise there's probably a better way/style of doing this, but I am only using this to learn if this kind of function chaining is possible, and if so, how to use it.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Are all the lines in the order you show us?

Comment: I copied and pasted it, working for me also.

Comment: The language attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4 and is removed (obsolete) in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no problem.
please check the link below.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vsrpC)

If it'll not work correctly, let me know more detailed information.